# Any jQuery Plugin Update Manager Utility?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

We use jQuery very heavily on a couple of projects and along with it we have loads (sometimes close to a dozen) plugins we use (jqGrid, jPolite, jGrowl, colorbox, layout, validate, formatters, mask, to name a few).

My fear is at some point managing which of these have updates that should be updated is going to become a challange. Anyone know of a tool (or perhaps another 'plugin') that will check all found plugins and report if they are the latest version ? A helper if you will that assists in keeping your jQuery plugins updated.

Thanks!

Comment: I starred this, and if no one answers with anything soon, I might just have to make my own to open source. I'll start once I configure my new server, which should give enough time for answers.

Comment: http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-dev/browse_thread/thread/82868bd0b3893da7/c2183c3f3f3745d1?pli=1 I think the jQuery Dev's are addressing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you want something like perl's CPAN, or Ruby Gems, but strictly for jQuery?

There is not such a thing to my knowledge, although it would be extremely cool and useful.

Since the plugin DB already basically exists (although I doubt how current it all is), How hard would it be to write a wrapper around it?

If you want to start a project, lemme know, we'd have to get the JQ.org folks in on it though.

Comment: Yea like apt-get but for jQuery Plugins ;)

Comment: So no one would be interested in working on a project that is more like apt-get/Ruby Gems/CPAN for jquery?

Comment: could be interesting. me and someone else i know might be willing.

Comment: @Chad Hello, I'm in :) Just sent you an email.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of adding in one more tool, I suggest you do this with one you are already using: The version control system. Most decent version control software supports external includes which you can use to keep your plugins up to date.

Say we want to include the latest *mousewheel* plugin in our SVN project, in your plugins folder do:

```
svn propset svn:externals "mwheel http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/svn/tags/plugins/mousewheel/3.0/" .
svn commit
svn update
```

This will create a folder called *mwheel* and keep it updated with whatever is in the remote repository whenever you update locally.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of anything exactly like what you are looking for, but I do have some ideas for now. Several of the plugins you use have RSS feeds, you could watch those. Others you could write a cron job or two to update the projects from the source.

Comment: I don't know that you'd want autoupdates, thats for sure, but having a Gems style utility would be nice. See my answer plz.

Comment: i was thinking of making something that would update a "branch", updating you whenever it detected a change. that way, you could decide to pull in the update yourself.